# Why this simple sql transaction wanna a S lock more after it holding an X lock?

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

my table's definition is like:

```
 CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `a` int,
  `b` int,
  PRIMARY KEY (`a`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_b` (`b`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and Isolation Level is: Read Committed (RC)

and query sql is like: `update test_table set a=LAST_INSERT_ID(a + 1) WHERE b= 1;`

when multiple clients requests to execute the same SQL at the same time, mysql maybe occur a deadlock error, and deadlock log is like :

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2020-05-26 18:04:12 0x7efb06c5d700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 261901143, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 6018875, OS thread handle 139617907197696, query id 3320727857 10.202.6.165 ma88 updating
update test_table set a=LAST_INSERT_ID(a + 1) WHERE b=1
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 6485 page no 4 n bits 272 index idx_b of table test_db.test_table trx id 261901143 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 148 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 06; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 00aeae62; asc    b;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 261901142, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting, thread declared inside InnoDB 4999
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 6018874, OS thread handle 139616615520000, query id 3320727856 10.202.6.165 ma88 updating
update test_table set a=LAST_INSERT_ID(a + 1) WHERE b=1
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 6485 page no 4 n bits 272 index idx_b of table test_db.test_table trx id 261901142 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 148 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 06; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 00aeae62; asc    b;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 6485 page no 4 n bits 272 index idx_b of table test_db.test_table trx id 261901142 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 148 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 2; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 1; hex 06; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 00aeae62; asc    b;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

via this deadlock log, I found that:
the transation-1 is waiting for the an X lock which is holding by transaction-2, and transaction-2 want a S Lock for the same data, then deadlock.

what i couldn't understand is why the transaction-2 want a S Lock while it hold an X Lock in this case.

can anyone give me an answer or some idea?

Comment: Are you implementing a "sequence generator"?

Answer (score 0):

Consider pulling the `UPDATE` out of the transaction.  It may lead to "burning" some sequence numbers.